# Clojurescript DOM interface

Tags: dom, clojure, clojurescript

Is there a Clojurescript library which makes the DOM look like a Clojure data structure ? I found a few libraries like Enfocus which do certain kinds of DOM manipulation, but what I want is to be able to treat the DOM like this:

```
(get dom id) - returns element called id in dom
(get dom id create-fn) - return element if exists, otherwise creates it
(update-in dom [:body this that] update-fn) - set attribute on a DOM element 
(assoc parent-element id child-element) - associate child element with parent
(conj parent child) - append child element to parent element
```

and so on

Comment: ok just found Domina - nearest thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure data structures are all persistent, but in your example it seems like you want to side effect (i.e., hit the DOM in place to change it).

That's a pretty procedural/imperative approach, so it may be worth stepping back and reformulating the problem in a more functional style.
My personal philosophy is to treat "views as data", and model it using Clojure's persistent data structures up until the last minute when I need to render.

Are you familiar with Hiccup?
The idea is to represent an HTML or SVG DOM using plain vectors and maps:

```
[:div {:with "attribute"} "and" [:span "children"]]
```

which you can construct by composing plain old Clojure functions.
In Clojure you can render this into HTML (using the original Hiccup library), but there are at least two ClojureScript libraries that render directly into (potentially existing) DOM structures.
[Crate](https://github.com/ibdknox/crate) is a close port of Hiccup, and [Singult](https://github.com/lynaghk/singult) has some additional semantics like D3.js-inspired data binding (Singult is actually written in CoffeeScript, so it's usable from plain JavaScript and is faster than Crate).

My [C2](https://github.com/lynaghk/c2) library builds data-binding semantics on top of Singult for keeping the DOM in sync with underlying data.
Consider this template for a TODO list:

```
(bind! "#main"
        [:section#main {:style {:display (when (zero? (core/todo-count)) "none")}}
        [:input#toggle-all {:type "checkbox"
                            :properties {:checked (every? :completed? @core/!todos)}}]
        [:label {:for "toggle-all"} "Mark all as complete"]
        [:ul#todo-list (unify (case @core/!filter
                                :active    (remove :completed? @core/!todos)
                                :completed (filter :completed? @core/!todos)
                                ;;default to showing all events
                                @core/!todos)
                              todo*)]])
```

(taken from [C2 TodoMVC implementation](https://github.com/lynaghk/c2-demos/blob/master/todoMVC/src/cljs/imtodo/list.cljs)).
Things like whether or not the "check all" box is checked is derived directly from the underlying data (stored in an atom).
Whenever that data changes, the template will be re-run and the dom automatically updated.

The basic idea is to build mappings in the forward direction from your application data to Hiccup data structures, and then let the library take care of syncing the DOM (adding/removing children, attributes, &c.).
If you don't have to concern yourself with the state of the DOM (has this already been added? do I need to toggle some class?) then a lot of incidental complexity falls away.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually thinking in terms of removing previous DOM elements and swapping them with newly generated ones from treating DOM fragments as Clojure-style persistant structures (but implemented as "immutable" DOM fragments). However, now that I think about it, it would probably be slow and wasteful. I will try your library...can it do SVG ?

Comment: hi, I tried the bar-chart example at http://keminglabs.com/c2/, and I get "Uncaught Error: TODO: return map of element styles". Also it took a while to work out which things to :require, :use and :use-macros, as most of the examples are isolated code fragments. Looks interesting though. How do you manage the mapping of data to dom elements wrt the identity of those nodes ? How does unify know which data correspond to which nodes in the dom, and whether or not to add new ones ?

Comment: Yep, it can handle SVG just fine. Singult will automatically namespace the common SVG elements (<g>, <rect>, &c.) for you too (so you don't have to say, e.g., `[:svg:rect {:x 1}]`.

Comment: Mapping against nodes uses index by default, but you can provide unify with an optional `:key-fn` argument and give it a function f(datum, index) whose return value will be used to identify that node. The relevant source is here: https://github.com/lynaghk/singult/blob/master/src/coffee/Singult.coffee#L198

Comment: ok I got it working for a simple line chart updating dynamically using (bind! (unify & the code is certainly much more concise than my previous add-or-update manual dom manipulation code. Updating SVG via Clojurescript in Firefox is really slow (1 update/sec is all I can afford)! Chrome can handle updates every 100ms - that's receiving JSON, converting to Clojure maps & mapping those to an SVG chart. Do you have a group for C2 ? Can't find any reference on the github pages or google groups

Comment: There is a very new google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/c2-cljs (I just added to the C2 readme, thanks for the note). As for your speed concerns, it's hard to say without looking at the code. Make sure you are using the latest version of lein cljsbuild (0.2.3 now, I believe), since the last few cljs complier versions are much faster. Also, if you're not using advanced compilation, try turning it on---some things get two or three times faster.